# Проверить, есть ли View с заданным ID

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть набор элементов типа ViewGroup и есть код, обрабатывающий эти элементы.
Нужно, сделать так, что если внутри элемента есть определённый вложенный элемент, то что-то с ним сделать.
Например, если внутри есть TextView с id=title, то установить ему какой-то заголовок.

```
for (item in items) {
    val nested: TextView? = item.findViewById(R.id.title)
    if (nested !== null) {
        nested.text = "Title"
    }
}
```

Однако, если ни в одном из этих элементов не будет нужного id, то тогда и константа `R.id.title` не сгенерируется.
Каким другим образом можно посмотреть, есть ли такой id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути идентификаторы хранятся в генерируемом класса R.java, который выглядит примерно так:

```
public final class R {  
    //blah-blah
    public static final class id {  
        public static final int title=0x7f070000;  
        //blah-blah
    }  
}
```

Надо попробовать наличие поля `R.id.title` через рефлексию (сорри, что на Java):

```
Class<?> rIdClass = R.id.class;
Field titleField = rIdClass.getField("title");
if(titleField!=null) {
    //bingo есть контакт
}
```